# Postgresql LIKE - find UTF-8 variants of ASCII text

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I'm trying to query a `PostgreSQL` table for rows where a column contains ASCII letters:

```
SELECT p.* FROM person AS p WHERE p.surname LIKE 'e%';
```

The database contains `UTF-8` strings. For example:

```
Éxample
Ěxample
```

I need to find rows that have only ASCII `e` (or `E`). Why does the above query not work?

Comment: What is your query actually returning? Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`unaccent` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html):

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

SELECT * FROM (
  VALUES
    ('Éxample'),
    ('Ěxample')
 ) v(s)
 WHERE lower(unaccent(s)) LIKE 'e%'
```